# Does Firebase's putData (Storage) and setData (Database) keep trying until success/failure?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

And what is the failure predicated on? The only obvious thing I can think of is authentication issues. The only other issue I can think of is connectivity and that's precisely where my question is. Does Firebase keep trying and trying until success (or another failure that I can't think of besides authentication)? Or does it just try once and if connectivity is bad, completion block returns error (failure)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for Firestore Database (not Storage) it's literally one [line](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline). As for Firebase RTDB (or whatever it's called), i'm pretty sure it's similarly one or two lines. For storage, check out [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#full_example) link and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress) link.

Sorry new things came up (not that anyone is probably reading this....but for documentation):
Both Firestore DTB and Storage, there is persistence as mentioned, but it's cache...not local storage. Meaning it's only "stored" until the session is over.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase client SDKs for Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database, and Cloud Storage automatically retry on the client, and generally don't fail due to temporary conditions.  They will fail in the case of a configuration problem, authentication failures, and anything where it's determined that a retry will never succeed.  Network connectivity problems are retried.

The Cloud Storage SDK might have a limit to the number of retries, as it doesn't try to maintain a persistent connection to the server like the database products.  You can examine all the source code for yourself on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk).